# SignalR derived types

Tags: c#, json.net, signalr

Hello I'm using signalR 2.02 , I can not get the correct derived class in my client .

I have the following situation

```
Class A {}
Class B : A{}

Class Other
{ 
   public A _member {get;set}
}

 Other instance = new Other() { _member = new B()}
```

I sent my instance from hub to the client , i expect on the client side i will see _member type as B , but i see it as A .

I've tried changing the serializer on the server side as follows , but to no effect

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
};
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

Comment: Are you using a IoC like Ninject?

Comment: I'm not using any IOC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve by defining the serializer to include full types when needed (The default is not to include them).

On the server side :

```
var serializer = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(JsonSerializer)) as JsonSerializer; 
serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

On the client side :

```
 _connection = new HubConnection(http://localhost:8080);
 _hubProxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
 _hubProxy.JsonSerializer.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

Comment: This does not work for me. If I set it to Auto, nothing changes and I still receive the base class on the server. If I set it to anything else (Objects, or All), it already throws an "error 500 Internal Server Error" on the _hubProxy.Start() method so it seems the connection itself already fails. Either way it doesn't work.... Any help?